# Conditions for $a^n-b^n\:$|$b^{kn-1}$ to be true

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I am attempting to solve the problem of knowing the conditions for when $a^n-b^n\:$|$b^{kn-1}$ $\left\{a>b,\:\left(a,\:b,\:n,\:k\right)\in \mathbb{Z}^{\ge }\right\}$ is true  , however, I have no idea how to figure this out... I have an idea of what the conditions might be, but I don't know how to show it mathematically.  Any help with this would be nice. Thanks.

(Also, sorry if I didn't show some of the math with correct use of symbols, I'm still pretty new to this)

Comment: It would be good to know the idea that you have, since the subject involves layers upon layers upon layers of different complexity levels.

Comment: I'm trying to prove my conjecture, that when a unique prime factor (I call it $P$) of $a^n-b^n$ appears for the lowest value of $n$ that appears for two numbers, $a$ and $b$ in the expression $a^n-b^n$, then $P$|$a^{kn+M}-b^{kn+M}$ will never be true, for $\left\{a>b,\:n>M>0,\:\left(a,\:b,\:k,\:n,\:M\right)\in \mathbb{Z}^{\ge }\right\}$, and I've gotten up to the point where if I can state the conditions for what I originally posted, I can prove the conjecture.

Comment: but all I need to know is my initial question